# Virtual Machine software with templating and launching multiple instances of the template

Tags: virtual-machine

Amazon EC2 lets you bundle an instance into an AMI (Amazon Machine Image), think of it like a building a template. Then you can rapidly launch multiple instances of that image.

***Is there a virtualization software I can install in-house that provides similar functionality?***

---

I currently use Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012R2 and I could export a machine and then import it back in multiple times; but I am looking for something that can be deployed much more rapidly. I need to be able to quickly deploy 20 or more instances of the template I just built. Think scalability.

#### Use case:

I want to setup a *Template VM* with a Windows OS and install custom software that will connect to an application I am building. The custom client software will perform automated tests against the server application I am building. Once the Template VM is complete I would shut it down and then tell the ***{insert software name here}*** to launch 20 instances of the template.

After the testing is complete I may need to modify the template and then do the test again. So manually exporting and then importing it back in 20 times is not feasible.

Comment: There are quite a few that can do this, could you add requirements that would help narrow down the search?

Comment: I can't really think of any requirements right now for this... I am using Hyper-V on Windows Server 2012R2 and templating doesn't appear to be a feature built-in to that product. So i am looking for others that definitely have the feature.

Comment: You could use virtual box and then just copy and paste a template virtual machine file.

Comment: I suppose i could also export a Hyper-V machine and then import it again, and again, multiple times. But i am looking for something that is able to be deployed much more rapidly, like with Amazon EC2. I will update the question to better explain.